# Visual Studio 2012 crashes when trying to open a WPF project

Tags: wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2012, crash, attach-to-process

Whenever I open a WPF project, Visual Studio crashes. I start a second instance and attach the process to the first instance and I receive the following error once the project is "opened":

> > *An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingFieldException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.LanguageService.CSharp.dll*
> >
> > *Additional information: Field not found: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Progression.Actions.GetNodeAtSourcePosition'.*

I'm not entirely sure what to do. I have reinstalled Visual Studio once before and the error still occurs. Any help on this problem would be wonderful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem when creating a new project with VS2012. Applying VS2012 Update 1 did the trick for me.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35774

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a Beta Version of Visual studio installed in your system prior to this?  What is your current version of VS?  If yes, then you need to remove all the components of VS Beta version manually.